# Python: Adding new line after return in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, line, new-operator, return

I am new to python and faced the following problem.. I am trying to do a recursive sum function but the sum does not get returned on a new line

For example, sum(2,2) should return

```
4
2
```

sum(2,3) will return

```
6
4
2
```

But I get 4 2 and 6 4 2 all on the same line. This is my code:

```
def sum(a,b):
    if a>0 and b>0:
        return str(a*b) + " " + str(sum(a,b-1))
    else:
        return ""
```

I have tried use changing " " to "\n" but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sum(a,b):
    if a>0 and b>0:
        return str(a*b) + "\n" + str(sum(a,b-1))
    else:
        return ""
```

works fine here.

Comment: oh seems like it worked again.. I don't know if there is something wrong with my compiler.. thanks anyway

Comment: @JustToHelp, it should be related to the specific execution environment (like idle, ipython, or any kind of shell environment)you are using. The compiler itself should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that changing " " to "\n" doesn't work, but did you try printing the result?

```
print sum(2, 2)
```